# Writing custom datasets and dataloaders with PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

Good afternoon!
I have questions about the following tutorial:
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html 1

I have a similar dataset (images + landmarks). I’ve built the custom dataloader following the tutorial and checked the types of dataloader components (torch.float64 for both images and landmarks).

Then I applied the dataloader to the classification model with this training class:

```
class Trainer():
  
    def __init__(self,criterion = None,optimizer = None,schedular = None):
      
        self.criterion = criterion
        self.optimizer = optimizer
        self.schedular = schedular
  
    def train_batch_loop(self,model,train_dataloader):    
        train_loss = 0.0
        train_acc = 0.0     
        for images,landmarks, labels in train_dataloader: 
                images = images.to(device)
                landmarks = landmarks.to(device)
                labels = labels.to(device)        
                self.optimizer.zero_grad()
```

I won’t be elaborating further because the training crushes at images = images.to(device) with the following error: AttributeError: ‘str’ object has no attribute 'to’

I don’t understand where this string is coming from if all the dataloader components are torch.float64.
I went back to check the initial data: in the tutorial, the landmarks are summarized in a pandas dataframe with landmark values as int64 and image name as “object”.
In my summary dataframe image name is an “object” as well and landmarks are numpy.float64. Again, no strings anywhere…
Appreciate any advice - what else should I check in addition to dtypes?

[image]

There are 30 cats and 48 landmarks for each image

The dataset is defined as follows:

```
class FaceLandmarksDataset(Dataset):

def __init__(self, data_frame, root_dir, transform=None):
    self.data_frame = data_frame
    self.root_dir = root_dir
    self.transform = transform

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.data_frame)

def __getitem__(self, idx):
    if torch.is_tensor(idx):
        idx = idx.tolist()

    img_name = os.path.join(self.root_dir,
                            self.data_frame.iloc[idx, 2])
    image = io.imread(img_name)
    landmarks = self.data_frame.iloc[idx, 3:]
    landmarks = np.array([landmarks])
    landmarks = landmarks.astype('float').reshape(-1, 2)
    labels = self.data_frame.iloc[idx, 1].reshape(1)
    sample = {'image': image, 'landmarks': landmarks, 'labels': labels}

    if self.transform:
        sample = self.transform(sample)

    return sample
```

Comment: Well the fact that a column in pandas has object datatype, does not mean that the the column does not contain strings.

Comment: Just let me check if I understand correctly - the only possible string is the image name. Later the name is used to find the corresponding image and process it with skimage. You suggest that maybe the image doesn't get processed and instead the model gets the image name only?

Comment: can you show how you load your data? Plus most models accept float32 as an input?

Comment: Show a sample of the dataframe

Comment: @EdwinCheong I will attach the screenshot as a new answer to the question, for better view

Comment: Please don't post "answers" which are not answers. And you better show how you define the dataloader

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov sorry, I couldn't post an image in a comment...

Comment: Hi i think you can explain what does these landmarks define, are there they the mask for image segmentation?

Comment: @EdwinCheong The 48 landmarks with 2 coordinates (x, y) are 48 points on a face image. The position of the points on an image should contribute to the correct classification (0 or 1) as opposed to classification based on images only

Answer (score 0):

Hi i made some changes based on your dataset, please make adjustment where you see fit, as i don't have your data i cannot test this out but this should be it based on on my understanding

```py
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
import os
from skimage import io
import numpy as np
from typing import Dict

class FaceLandmarksDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data_frame, root_dir, transform=None):
        self.data_frame = data_frame
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data_frame)

    def __getitem__(self, idx) -> Dict[str, torch.Tensor]:
        if torch.is_tensor(idx):
            idx = idx.tolist()

        img_name = os.path.join(self.root_dir,self.data_frame.iloc[idx]['image_name'])
        image = io.imread(img_name)
        landmarks = self.data_frame.iloc[idx, 3:].tolist()
        landmarks = np.array(landmarks)
        landmarks = landmarks.astype('float32').reshape(-1, 2)
        labels = self.data_frame.iloc[idx]['label']

        # Your transforming your image only therefore pass in the array
        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)

        # Create dictionary after finishing all transforms -> automatically becomes torch tensor when passed
        sample = {
            'image': image, 
            'landmarks': landmarks, 
            'labels': labels
        }
        return sample
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. Your suggestion to move dictionary creation after all transforms looks reasonable. I tried changing the code and got this error message: IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Will keep trying to fix...

Comment: Well, I've found the "magical" missing string :) In the trainer class function train_batch_loop the first for-loop (for images,landmarks, labels in train_dataloader) is incorrectly iterating over the dataloader items.
If I print out the type of images in for-loop, it shows a string, although if I iterate over the dataloader itself, the data type is correct (torch tensor). Now I have to fix the trainer function to correctly get the data.